# Certain SC Orchestrator Send E-Mail activities are sending 2 emails

Tags: windows, email, system-center

Also posted this on TechNet but barking up this tree too just in case. Not really sure what's going on here, but I have certain System Center Orchestrator (2012 R2) Runbooks that are sending multiple e-mails, when they are only supposed to send 1. Here's the flow of one particular Runbook environment:

```
Runbook 0: Time Monitor -> Schedule Check -> Invoke Runbook A (wait for completion) -> Invoke Runbook B (wait for completion) [end]

Runbook A: Send E-Mail activity (only receive 1 email) -> Bunch of Service-Stop activities [end]

Runbook B: Send E-Mail activity (only receive 1 email) -> Bunch of Service-Start activities -> Invoke Runbook C [end]

Runbook C: Get-Service-Status activities -> Send E-Mail activity (always get 2 of this email) [end]
```

I have 3 environments, Dev, Test, and Prod, and all 3 environments have Runbook C sending the final email twice. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but the nearly same e-mail activities from Runbooks A and B only send once. One thing I'm wondering is if it's because the e-mail activities from Runbook C are in HTML format since I am Subscribing the service status variables in the email body. But can't imagine why that would cause it.

It's not the most convenient thing to test either as I can't restart the services, even for Dev/Test, willy-nilly. But I am restarting Dev tonight at 8:30, so if anyone has any ideas, I can try to implement it today.

Thanks all, I'm probably just doing something stupid (long week).

EDIT: I ran a Message Trace in O365 and also examined the headers of the duplicate emails. They aren't technically "duplicates", but rather "multiples". They are 2 completely different email messages, even coming from 2 different outlook.com SMTP servers. So something in SCOrch is making it send out twice. Just wanted to rule out an issue with e-mail, and I think I have.

-Chris

Answer (score 0):

I had this when I addressed the email to several people.

I worked around it by using a junction after the send email.